# ssh-add is forgotten if new gnome-terminal is opened

Tags: ssh-agent

After a:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

I can log in to a "server" via ssh without pwd.

**Question:** But If I open a new gnome-terminal I have to do this again, why?

Using RHEL Desktop 6.6 with GNOME.

**UPDATE #1**: interesting, another RHEL Desktop doesn't runs ssh-agent, it only needs an "ssh-add" per boot. But issuing an "ssh-add" on the "bad desktop" only gives an error message: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

**UPDATE #2**: SSH_AUTH_SOCK is missing after a fresh reboot, maybe that is the problem?:

```
[user@notebook ~]$ env | grep SSH
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
[user@notebook ~]$
```

Comment: Actually gnome did the job (save ssh key) already, but I noticed gnome require you reboot once after `ssh-add`, otherwise you need `ssh-add` in each bash session "before reboot". This behaviour is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "env | grep SSH" is bad (regarding missing SSH_AUTH_SOCK):

vi ~/.bashrc

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`env | grep GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET | cut -d= -f2 | sed 's/$/.ssh/g'`
[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Answer (score 4):

`ssh-add` and `ssh` refer to a couple of environment variables to find the SSH agent to talk to: `SSH_AGENT_PID` and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. When you run

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

`ssh-agent` outputs the values and your shell interprets them; they are set in the shell the command is run from, **and that shell only**. Thus when you start a new terminal, the new shell in that terminal doesn't have those variables set appropriately and `ssh` can't find the agent.

If you have both terminals running, you can run

```
env | grep SSH
```

in the terminal you started the agent from, and set the values given in the new terminal. Then `ssh` should find the agent in the second terminal.

A better solution though is to use the SSH agent integration in GNOME, as provided by `gnome-keyring`. I'm not sure how things are set up in RHEL Desktop, but you can try simply running `ssh-add` without starting the agent beforehand...

The [GNOME keyring SSH](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh) documentation may be helpful; in particular, you may want to check whether the SSH Key Agent is enabled in your startup applications (in the GNOME properties).

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-agent -s` returns a few environment variables to be set, like so:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-OIohiYiJShSO/agent.11139; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=11140; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

While they carry over to processes launched from the shell these are set in, they do not apply to processes *not* launched from that shell. When you open a new gnome-terminal from the desktop or a menu, it is not launched via that shell, so it does not get the environment variables.

If you launch your new terminal from the shell you ran `` exec `ssh-agent -s` ``, in e.g. by typing `gnome-terminal &`, it will inherit the shell variables and it should work. Alternatively, you can call `ssh-agent` with a command, like so:

```
ssh-agent gnome-terminal &
```

It will then run that command with the necessary environment variables set.